# elasticsearch: failed to parse field of type [text]

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm getting this error, while trying to insert a document with an object `something`:

```
failed to parse field [alert.something] of type [text]
in document with id 'S7wzjXwBoPDEI_MgkgFb'. Preview of field's value: '{a=b}'",
```

This is the message:

```
{
          "random" : 1634334912,
          "alert" : {
            "app_key" : "abc",
            "host" : "prod-mongo-1",
            "check" : "heap_size",
            "status" : "warning",
            "something": {
              "a": "b"
            }
          }
}
```

This is the index template:

```
{
    "order" : 0,
    "index_patterns" : [
      "rawpayload-*"
    ],
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "mapping" : {
          "coerce" : "false",
          "nested_fields" : {
            "limit" : "50"
          },
          "depth" : {
            "limit" : "20"
          },
          "ignore_malformed" : "false"
        }
      }
    },
    "mappings" : {
      "_source" : {
        "enabled" : true
      },
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "alert_boject": {
            "path_match": "alert.*",
            "match_mapping_type" : "*",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties" : {
        "application" : {
          "index" : "false",
          "store" : true,
          "type" : "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Can you please point out or help me figure this out :) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `alert.*` can be a string or an object, add a new dynamic type mapping for objects.

Your current template accepts any JSON type for `alert_boject`:

```
"match_mapping_type" : "*",
```

But only maps to a JSON string - `text` - which won't work for objects:

```
"mapping": {
  "type": "text"
}
```

---

Modify the current template to only pick up on `text`:

```
{
  "alert_boject": {
    "path_match": "alert.*",
    "match_mapping_type" : "text",
    "mapping": {
      "type": "text"
    }
  }
}
```

And then create a new template based on the above - change the mapping type (`mapping.type`) to `object` so that it accepts an object & change `match_mapping_type` to `object` too.

This way you will have 2 templates triggered based on if you have a `text` field or an `object`.

```
"dynamic_templates":[
   {
      "alert_object_text":{
         "path_match":"alert.*",
         "match_mapping_type":"text",
         "mapping":{
            "type":"text"
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "alert_object_object":{
         "path_match":"alert.*",
         "match_mapping_type":"object",
         "mapping":{
            "type":"object"
         }
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: Thank you !! Should I add another object `dynamic_templates` or change `alert_object` ?

Comment: Wouldn't it cancel the mapping for `text` fields ?

Comment: Under alert field  can be objects, numbers and strings. What is the best way to handle it ?

Comment: Providing `*` to a mapping is not allowed, I get an error

Comment: Yup, as I've done below. it works !

Comment: I have another question please :)

Comment: Okay, wonderful. For any new questions, more than happy to help but please open a new one to not clutter the answer/comments! :)

Comment: I'd love your help on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69604154/elasticsearch-cannot-be-converted-to-long-without-data-loss

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is a solution but I'd love to hear some opinions.
I managed to mitigate the error by adding a template definition:

```
        {
          "alert_object_parser": {
            "path_match": "alert.*",
            "match_mapping_type" : "object",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "object"
            }
          }
        }
```

What do you think ?