# elasticsearch: cannot be converted to Long without data loss

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this message:

```
{
          "random" : 1634334912,
          "alert" : {
            "app_key" : "abc",
            "host" : "prod-mongo-1",
            "check" : "heap_size",
            "status" : "warning",
            "something": {
              "a": "b"
            }
            "number": <Value>

          }
}
```

The value of `number` can be either `1.572322062646`, `1572322062646` or `'1.57232116125E9'` (not the exact value, rather the type)

Do I have a way to mitigate this error using dynamic templates?

```
      "reason" : "1.572322062646 cannot be converted to Long without data loss"
```

Answer (score 1):

a long is an [integer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/number.html), which means it has to be a whole number. take a look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/number.html#_which_type_should_i_use, as you may want to use a `scaled_float`

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I ended up using ingest pipeline to save all fields as text